# Reverse match URL in Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a URL defined like this in Django:

```
# http://localhost:8000/quiz/grammar/beginner/1/question

url(r'^(?P<page_name>[-\w]+)/(?P<level>\w+)/(?P<quiz_id>\d+)/question/$', views.question, name='question')
```

If I pass the static values I don't get any errors:

```
<a href="{% url 'quiz:question' "fds" "fds" 1 %}">{{ i.name }}</a>
```

Since I am already on this page: `http://localhost:8000/quiz/grammar/beginner/` I thought of passing URL like this:

```
{% for i in quizes %}

    <a href="{% url 'quiz:question' i.id %}">{{ i.name }}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

I have `namespace` defined. But I get this error:

```
Reverse for 'question' with arguments '(1L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

I am doing like this in my view:

```
def question(request, quiz_id):
```

What's wrong?

**EDIT:** Tried this, still no luck:

```
def question(request, page_name, level, quiz_id):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url tag returns an absolute url. It is not aware of the page your are on, so you cannot leave out the the `level` and `quiz` arguments when using the tag.

If you have `page_name` and `level` in your template context, you can use these variables in the url tag.

```
<a href="{% url 'quiz:question' page_name level i.id %}">{{ i.name }}</a>
```

If you capture `page_name` and `level` arguments in your url, then you are correct to change your view function to accept them.

```
def question(request, page_name, level, quiz_id):
```

Comment: I don't have `template context` called `page_name` and `level`. Now, how should I capure `page_name` and `level` the the URL.

Comment: What are the url pattern and view serving `/quiz/grammar/beginner/`? Does it the url pattern capture `page_name` and `level`?

Comment: Capture? I don't think so! What would you suggest? Pass the context or capture the url pattern? If `capture` how to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your last comment. You need to pass `page_name` and  `level` in to the template context so that you can use them in the url tag. If you don't know how to do that, then you'll need to update your question with the url pattern and view that serve `/quiz/grammar/beginner/`, so that somebody can help you.